# Inserção de elementos HTML dentro de outro HTML Gerado com Jquery em uma mesma função

Tags: html, jquery, ajax

No meu seguinte código abaixo eu gostaria de inserir os dados vindo da requisição ajax, juntamente com os HTML do append() apenas nos elementos cujo id do input hidden fossem iguais ao `item.id` (do `objItens`). Porém todas as formas que eu imaginei não funcionam. Alguma dica de como posso implementar isso da melhor forma?

```
 function listaItensPorIdExecCadeia(objIdExecCadeia){

    var idExecucaoDaCadeia = [];

    objIdExecCadeia.map(cadeia => {

        $('#bloco-procedimento-lista-itens').append(`
        <h4>${cadeia.nome} #${cadeia.id}</h4>
        <input id="inputIdExecucaoDaCadeia" type="hidden" value="${cadeia.id}" /> 
        <ul id="procedimento-lista-itens" class="list-group">  
        </ul>     
        `);
        idExecucaoDaCadeia.push(cadeia.id);
    });

    for(var i = 0; i <= idExecucaoDaCadeia.length; i++){

        $.get(BASE_URL+'item/listar',{
            idItem: idExecucaoDaCadeia[i],
        },
        function(objResponse){

            var objItens = objResponse.strMessage;

            objItens.map(item => {
                    $('#procedimento-lista-itens').append(`
                    <li class="list-group-item cadeia-itens-lista">
                        <p>${item.nome}</p>
                        <div>
                            <a class="btn btn-default"><i class="fa fa-qrcode"></i></a>
                            <a class="btn btn-primary"><i class="fa fa-info-circle"></i></a>
                            <a class="btn btn-warning"><i class="fa fa-edit"></i></a>   
                            <a class="btn btn-danger"><i class="fa fa-times"></i></a>   
                        </div>
                    </li>          
                `);
            })
        },'JSON'
        );
    }
}
```

Comment: Qual é exatamente o erro?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Acontece você está criando elementos com `id` duplicado no seu `DOM` o que não é nada recomendado, adicione um identificador único para os seus elementos dinâmicos.

```
function listaItensPorIdExecCadeia(objIdExecCadeia){

    var idExecucaoDaCadeia = [];

    objIdExecCadeia.map(cadeia => {

        $('#bloco-procedimento-lista-itens').append(`
        <h4>${cadeia.nome} #${cadeia.id}</h4>
        <input id="inputIdExecucaoDaCadeia" type="hidden" value="${cadeia.id}" /> 
        <ul id="procedimento-lista-itens_${cadeia.id}" class="list-group">  
        </ul>     
        `);
        idExecucaoDaCadeia.push(cadeia.id);
    });

    for(var i = 0; i <= idExecucaoDaCadeia.length; i++){

        $.get(BASE_URL+'item/listar',{
            idItem: idExecucaoDaCadeia[i],
        },
        function(objResponse){

            var objItens = objResponse.strMessage;

            objItens.map(item => {
                    $('#procedimento-lista-itens_'+idExecucaoDaCadeia[i]).append(`
                    <li class="list-group-item cadeia-itens-lista">
                        <p>${item.nome}</p>
                        <div>
                            <a class="btn btn-default"><i class="fa fa-qrcode"></i></a>
                            <a class="btn btn-primary"><i class="fa fa-info-circle"></i></a>
                            <a class="btn btn-warning"><i class="fa fa-edit"></i></a>   
                            <a class="btn btn-danger"><i class="fa fa-times"></i></a>   
                        </div>
                    </li>          
                `);
            })
        },'JSON'
        );
    }
}
```

Abaixo deixei um exemplo removendo a sua consulta dos itens de detalhes e simulando o resultado.

```js
var cadeias = [{id: 1, nome: "teste"}, { id: 2, nome: "teste 2"}];
var itens = [{ cadeiaId: 1, nome: "sub teste 1 - 1"}, { cadeiaId: 1, nome: "sub teste 1 - 2"}, { cadeiaId: 2, nome: "sub teste 2 - 1"}, {cadeiaId: 2, nome: "sub teste 2 - 2"}];


function listaItensPorIdExecCadeia(objIdExecCadeia) {

  var idExecucaoDaCadeia = [];

  objIdExecCadeia.map(cadeia => {

    $('#bloco-procedimento-lista-itens').append(`
        <h4>${cadeia.nome} #${cadeia.id}</h4>
        <input id="inputIdExecucaoDaCadeia" type="hidden" value="${cadeia.id}" /> 
        <ul id="procedimento-lista-itens_${cadeia.id}" class="list-group">  
        </ul>     
        `);
    idExecucaoDaCadeia.push(cadeia.id);
  });

  for (var i = 0; i <= idExecucaoDaCadeia.length; i++) {

    var objItens = jQuery.grep(itens, function(n,j){
      return n.cadeiaId === idExecucaoDaCadeia[i];
    });

    objItens.map(item => {
      $('#procedimento-lista-itens_'+idExecucaoDaCadeia[i]).append(`
                    <li class="list-group-item cadeia-itens-lista">
                        <p>${item.nome}</p>
                        <div>
                            <a class="btn btn-default"><i class="fa fa-qrcode"></i></a>
                            <a class="btn btn-primary"><i class="fa fa-info-circle"></i></a>
                            <a class="btn btn-warning"><i class="fa fa-edit"></i></a>   
                            <a class="btn btn-danger"><i class="fa fa-times"></i></a>   
                        </div>
                    </li>          
                `);
    });

  }

}

listaItensPorIdExecCadeia(cadeias);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<html>
<body>
  <div id="bloco-procedimento-lista-itens"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Obrigado Leandro, sua dica de gerar os IDs dinamicamente foi crucial para resolver meu problema.